# Python: calculate (1/1) + (1 + 2) / 2 + ... + (1 + 2 + ... + n) / n

Tags: python

The use of for loops is not allowed. This program is designed to calculate values up to number 'n' which is a value entered by the user. Help on this would be appreciated. A photo of the problem and my code so far is listed below:

[image]

```
import math

counterN = 0 #Numerator
counterD = 0 #Denominator
divNumber = 0 #Numerator/Denominator
nValue = 0  #Variable to add numberator values to
dValue = 0  #Variable to add denominaor values to

#Prompts user for a 
print("Please enter a value for calculation: ")
number = int(input())
if (number <= 0):
    print("Invalid input given.")

#Adds the numerator up to number entered by user
while (counterN <= number):
    counterN = counterN + 1
    nValue += counterN
    #Denominator calculation
    counterD = counterD + 1
    dValue += counterD
    divNumber = nValue / dValue
    divNumber += divNumber


#Outputs value to user
print("The result is" , divNumber)
print(counterN, nValue)
```

Comment: Your code just computes the same value twice, divides them with 1 as the result and then adds 1 to itself, until it has done it `number` times. Try stepping through your code and keep track of what values the variables assume. You're making this too complicated and it's not clear what you expect as an answer (other than getting someone to answer the problem for you) [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion for such problems. I've written a recursive solution for you which I found very intuitive-

```
global SUM
SUM = 0

def fracSUMCalc(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    SUM = fracSUMCalc(n-1) + (sum(range(1, n+1)) / n)
    return SUM

print(fracSUMCalc(n=998))
```

This prints out `249749.5` which is the answer to the sum of your series till `n=998`. You can vary n as per your need.

*Please note that this solution will work fine on any standard modern day laptop till `n=998`. For `n>998`, you'd either have to increase your machine's recursion depth limit or use a different approach to develop a more efficient program.*

Comment: I wish I could use this, but I'm in an intro class. We can only use while loops and if statements

Comment: Once you learn recursive constructs, try to solve this problem again just for your own understanding and then revisit this solution. For now, you can go for solution given by @Iain Shelvington. It uses a math trick and is a clever one. Make sure you understand the maths behind it before submitting.

Comment: @myVerma We can do even better by simply executing `return 0.25 * n * (n + 3)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that just uses no loops or recursion at all, just maths

```
def frac_series_sum(n):
    return n + sum(range(n)) * 0.5

print(frac_series_sum(1)) # 1.0
print(frac_series_sum(5)) # 10.0
print(frac_series_sum(100)) # 2575.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown (see below) that your sum is equal to

[image]

for any natural number `n`.

Thus, this function calculates the sum you want. It does not involve any recursion, `for` loops or any kind of iteration (it is `O(1)`):

```
def my_calc(n):
    "Returns 1/1 + (1 + 2)/2 + ... + (1 + 2 + ... + n)/n"
    return 0.25 * n * (n + 3)
```

This is as *efficient* as it gets.

If you are not allowed to use the solution above and you need to use a `while` loop:

```
def my_inefficient_calc(n):
    "Returns 1/1 + (1 + 2)/2 + ... + (1 + 2 + ... + n)/n"
    result = 0
    i = 1
    while (i <= n):
        result += (sum(range(1, i + 1))) / i
        i += 1
    return result
```

If you are not allowed to use the built-in `sum` function, you can calculate the sum using a nested `while` loop:

```
def even_less_efficient(n):
    "Returns 1/1 + (1 + 2)/2 + ... + (1 + 2 + ... + n)/n"
    result = 0
    i = 1
    while (i <= n):
        inner_sum = 0
        k = 1
        while (k <= i):
            inner_sum += k
            k += 1
        result += inner_sum / i
        i += 1
    return result
```

- `i` is a loop variable (counter) for the outer loop. It ranges from `i = 1` up to `n`.
- `k` is a loop variable (counter) for the inner loop. It ranges from `k = 1` up to `i`.
- The inner loop is responsible for calculating the sum in the numerator for each term. This sum is stored in `inner_sum`.
- Once the sum is calculated for a given `i` (i.e. once we are done with the inner loop), we divide this sum by `i` to get one of the terms in the mathematical expression.
- The outer loop is responsible for summing all of the terms from `i = 1` up to `n`.

**Intuitive Proof**

---

How did I arrive at this?

You want a program that calculates the following sum:

[image]

This is an elegant solution that has stuck with me for a long time that I will never forget. I once learned in real analysis of a  famous mathematician who at the age of 5 (if I remember correctly) reasoned that the sum of `i` from `i = 1` up to `k` is:

[image]

He did so by writing out the sum twice, but the second in reverse order:

```
(sum of i from i = 1 to k) = 1 + 2       + ... + (k - 1) + k
(sum of i from i = 1 to k) = k + (k - 1) + ... + 2       + 1
----------------------------------------------------------
                          (k+1)+ (k+1)   +...  + (k+1)   + (k+1)  # k terms
```

He noticed that each sum has `k` numbers and the sum of each column is equal to `k + 1`. So, if you add the two sums, you get

```
2 * (sum of i from i = 1 to k) = k * (k + 1)
```

Thus

```
(sum of i from i = 1 to k) = (k * (k + 1)) / 2
```

which is the same as the result in the second image above.

Substitution of this result into the left-hand-side of the expression in the first image:

[image]

Now apply the result that we derived again to the last expression above:

[image]

Thus

[image]

or

```
0.25 * n * (n + 3)
```

**Note**: A formal proof of the above result would be a proof by induction to show it is true for any natural number `n`. This proof by induction part is the easy part. I have omitted such a proof as the above should be obvious to anyone that sees it.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong (I had forgotten to divide by `k`, I was just doing ´1 + (1+2) + (1+2+3) + ...´.

Comment: @Dominique No worries. I appreciate you taking the time to read the post though to make me double check.